# How can I make a system tool available to a Bazel run_shell rule?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I'm trying to run a third party bash script from a Bazel rule. The script runs a `.jar` file that goes through some source files and generates code from them.

The issue I'm having is that, while the script works fine from a `genrule` (or when executed outside Bazel) when inside the `run_shell` it throws an error:
`execvp: No such file or directory`.

Apparently the Java program is trying to run `cc1`, the preprocessor tool, and is not finding it. But even after I included the tool as an implicit dependency through the `args` of the rule, the error remains.

I have thought maybe the tool is available in the runfiles, but is not in the `$PATH` variable inside the sandbox. Is this the case? And if so, how could I add it to the sandbox's `$PATH`?

(Sorry for the lack of code examples, but the code is on an airgapped environment)